# How to obtain a absolute of a number in Xilinx Simulink?

Tags: fpga, xilinx, system-generator

I need to get the absolute of the signal in Xilinx Simulink.

I can use a mcode block and write matlab code to achieve it. But, just curious if there is a better way of doing it.

I am very new to using Simulink(Xilinx). Is there any abs block as in Simulink in Xilinx library.

Thanks

Comment: Well, I modeled it. I basically used a compare to Zero block and followed by a 2-to-1 Multiplexer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xilinx have the following Answer Record:

http://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/10975.htm

which pretty much covers what you've already done!

Comment: Thanks, 1 more solution. and more optimal since Compare to zero has a latency of 1 clock cycle whereas Slice block doesn't require any additional hardware resource

Comment: If you make the latency of a "compare to zero" 0 it will probably result in just a slice in the end.  The optimisers are good at that sort of thing.